# Is there a difference between "be nice with" and "be nice to"?

Tags: usage

I got an edit correction in another Stack Exchange. I wrote a sentence with an "x person is nice with" statement in the sense of a person being friendly to other, and it was edited to "x person is nice to". I've seen "be nice with" being used several times, I wonder if this is still incorrect or if there is a difference among both sentences.

Comment: According to this https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/245630 explanation, "with me" might indicate physically and "to me" might mean emotionally. Also *be nice TO me* is more common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most contexts, 'to' is *directional*, so "be nice *to*..." somebody means to direct that niceness towards them. 'With' has many different uses but among its many definitions it can mean to 'go alongside', 'to go in the same direction as'.

"Be nice with...." someone is an idiomatic way of saying "treat them nicely". So, in context, they do essentially mean the same.